# Accounts problems after Meteor 1.6

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

it seems as I updated to Meteor 1.6 I am having some problems with accounts password.
I am not sure it is about Meteor 1.6 but the problems haven't happened before the upgrade.
New users when registered being instantly logged in as it should be with `Accounts.createUser` however if I log out and then try to login I get `User Not Found`. But in the db I can see the user.
Another problem, after verifying the email in the db the status is still `verified: false`
And I am having similar problems with other functions for enrolling and so on.
One thing that I note of difference between new users and old users is the structure of their emails. Previously it was

```
"emails" : [
        {
            "address" : "myMail@gmail.com",
            "verified" : false
        }
    ]
```

Now it is

```
"emails" : {
        "0" : {
            "address" : "myMail@gmail.com",
            "verified" : false
        }
    }
```

This doesn't seem to be a big of change but maybe the problem is connected with this.
And just in case I have accounts-meld packages

Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: Do you login via email or username? `Meteor.loginWithPasswort` supports both so which one do you use and what happens if you try the other one?

Comment: @Jankapunkt I use it with email.

Comment: Ok and login with username works as expected?